# disable screen orientation in swift 4 for UINavigationController and UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, autorotate

Hi I am trying to stop the autorotation in one of the view controller in my project. In the snap shot below,
[image]

I have a starting `UINavigationController` and then a `UIViewController`. I have implemented the following code to stop the autorotation:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
    }

    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        get {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
        }
    }}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        return .landscape
    }
  }
```

But the above code doesn't seem to call and not taking any effect. I am using `Xcode 9` and `swift 4.0`.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Regards,
neena

Comment: did you change your `Info.plist` adding the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` ?

Comment: if i will change the info.plist then it would be for the whole application i guess but i want this behaviour in some view controllers not all over the application.

Comment: `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`: specifies the interface orientations that the app supports.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class and set it to `UINavigationController`, then use this new class in your Storyboard/XIB

In your extension :

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {     
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return topViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? super.shouldAutorotate
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
}
```

In your controller :

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: Its not working :( . I have all this code in place and when I rotate my device its changing it orientation.

Comment: I don't know whats going on. Even the edited version is also not working. I have tried to debug it. The break point never comes on the two properties.

Comment: I just found out something very interesting. The above solution is working on iphone but on iPad it isn't working unless the "show full screen" flag is tick in project settings but again if I set the show full screen flag in project it wouldn't let me do the multitasking on ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I looked all over stack overflow and tried many of the solutions, and none of them worked. I found this solution on the apple developer forums, and it worked like a charm.

I'm adding their solution here in hopes that it will be easier for others to find in the future, giving credit to the [author](http://marucca), and linking to [their post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62008).

**Add to your AppDelegate file:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return self.orientationLock

}

struct AppUtility {

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {

        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {

            delegate.orientationLock = orientation

        }

    }

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        self.lockOrientation(orientation)

        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

    }

}
```

**Add to the viewcontroller that you want to force an orientation:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.all)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested your solution but the problem is still same. The solution works on iPhone but it doesn't work on iPad. As I mentioned earlier in one of my comment that it will only work on iPad if the "show full screen" is tick. If you know any extended solution for iPad that works without this flag to tick on then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a just a clarification for TagTaco's answer above.

make a custom class

```
class CustomUINavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

Now you can create a navigation controller like this:

```
let navController = CustomUINavigationController(rootViewController: YourController())
```

Hope it helps someone.
Cheers.